# How to get the most frequent row in table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, frequency, mode

How to get the most frequent row in a DataFrame?
For example, if I have the following table:

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1     A
1      1      0     A
2      0      1     A
3      1      1     A
4      1      0     B
5      1      0     C
```

Expected result:

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1     A
```

EDIT: I need the most frequent row (as one unit) and not the most frequent column value that can be calculated with the `mode()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pandas 1.1.0. is possible to use the method [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) to count unique rows in DataFrame:

```
df.value_counts()
```

Output:

```
col_1  col_2  col_3
1      1      A        2
       0      C        1
              B        1
              A        1
0      1      A        1
```

This method can be used to find the most frequent row:

```
df.value_counts().head(1).index.to_frame(index=False)
```

Output:

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1     A
```

Answer (score 12):

Check `groupby`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().sort_values().tail(1).reset_index().drop(0,1)
   col_1  col_2 col_3  
0      1      1     A
```

Comment: Alternative `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size().sort_values('size').tail(1).drop('size', 1)`

Answer (score 10):

With NumPy's [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
In [92]: u,idx,c = np.unique(df.values.astype(str), axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)

In [99]: df.iloc[[idx[c.argmax()]]]
Out[99]: 
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0      1      1     A
```

If you are looking for performance, convert the string column to numeric and then use `np.unique` -

```
a = np.c_[df.col_1, df.col_2, pd.factorize(df.col_3)[0]]
u,idx,c = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with groupby and size:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()
result = df.iloc[[df["size"].idxmax()]].drop(["size"], axis=1)
result.reset_index(drop=True) #this is just to reset the index
```

Comment: You have to check your code. How do you get the `'size'` column?

Comment: You are right, I added the "as_index=False" that I somehow omitted when writing it down. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`npi_indexed` library helps to perform some actions on 'groupby' type of problems with less script and similar performance as `numpy`. So this is alternative and pretty similar way to @Divakar's `np.unique()` based solution:

```
arr = df.values.astype(str)
idx = npi.multiplicity(arr)
output = df.iloc[[idx[c.argmax()]]]
```